# How to integrate SAP BusinessObjects integration option in Microsoft SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, business-objects

I successfully installed SAP integration option for SharePoint 4.0 in SharePoint server. After installation I was able to see all the SAP web parts available for adding in existing site.

I created a new site page and tried to insert SAP BusinessObjects web part.
I am getting HTTP status 500 instead of info view logon page.

Help me in debugging this issue.